# Understanding Javascript scope with "var that = this"

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following property method in an object:

```
  onReady: function FlashUpload_onReady()
  {
     Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet({
       url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "org/app/classification",
       successCallback: {
         fn: function (o) {
           var classButtonMenu = [],
               menuLabel, that = this;

           var selectButtonClick = function (p_sType, p_aArgs, p_oItem) {
               var sText = p_oItem.cfg.getProperty("text");
               that.classificationSelectButton.set("label", sText);
           };

           for (var i in o.json.items) {
             classButtonMenu.push({
               text: o.json.items[i].classification,
               value: o.json.items[i].filename,
               onClick: {fn: selectButtonClick}
             });
           }

           this.classificationSelectButton = new YAHOO.widget.Button({
             id: this.id + "-appClassification",
             type: "menu",
             label: classButtonMenu[0].text,
             name: "appClassification",
             menu: classButtonMenu,
             container: this.id + "-appClassificationSection-div"
           });
         },
         scope: this
       },
       failureMessage: "Failed to retrieve classifications!"
     });
```

It took me some guess work to figure out that in the `selectButtonClick` function that I needed to reference `that` instead of `this` in order to gain access to `this.classificationSelectButton` (otherwise it comes up `undefined`), but I'm uncertain as to why I can't use `this`.  My best guess is that any properties in the overall object that gets referenced within `new YAHOO.widget.Button` somehow looses scope once the constructor function is called.

Could someone please explain why it is that I have to reference `classificationSelectButton` with `var that = this` instead of just calling `this.classificationSelectButton'?

Comment: A great explanation on mysterious this behavior based on context [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/this/)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The most important thing to understand is that a function object **does not have a fixed `this` value** -- the value of `this` changes depending on how the function is called. We say that a function is *invoked with some a particular `this` value* -- the `this` value is determined at invocation time, not definition time.

- If the function is called as a "raw" function (e.g., just do `someFunc()`), `this` will be the global object (`window` in a browser) (or `undefined` if the function runs in strict mode).
- If it is called as a method on an object, `this` will be the calling object.
- If you call a function with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), `this` is specified as the first argument to `call` or `apply`.
- If it is called as an event listener (as it is here), `this` will be the element that is the target of the event.
- If it is called as a constructor with `new`, `this` will be a newly-created object whose prototype is set to the `prototype` property of the constructor function.
- If the function is the result of a [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) operation, the function will always and forever have `this` set to the first argument of the `bind` call that produced it. (This is the single exception to the "functions don't have a fixed `this`" rule -- functions produced by `bind` actually *do* have an immutable `this`.)

Using `var that = this;` is a way to store the `this` value at function *definition time* (rather than function *execution time*, when `this` could be anything, depending on how the function was invoked). The solution here is to store the outer value of `this` in a variable (traditionally called `that` or `self`) which is included in the scope of the newly-defined function, because newly-defined functions have access to variables defined in their outer scope.

Comment: This is a very elegant explanation of a subject that eludes most developers, great work.

Comment: Very useful! I wrote a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/cyrus-and/8169187) that summarizes all these cases.

Comment: @apsillers You're the top link of the week in the /r/javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Because `this` changes its value based on the context it's run in.

Inside your `selectButtonClick` function the `this` will refer to that function's context, not the outer context. So you need to give `this` a different name in the outer context which it can be referred to by inside the `selectButtonClick` function.

Answer (score 3):

There's lexical scope: variables declared in functions and arguments passed to functions are visible only inside the function (as well as in its inner functions).

```
var x = 1; // `1` is now known as `x`
var that = this; // the current meaning of `this` is captured in `that`
```

The rules of lexical scope are quite intuitive. You assign variables explicitly.

Then there's dynamic scope: `this`. It's a magical thing that changes it's meaning depending on how you call a function. It's also called *context*. There are several ways to assign a meaning to it.

Consider a function:

```
function print() { console.log(this); }
```

**Firstly**, the default context is `undefined` in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) and the global object in normal mode:

```
print(); // Window
```

**Secondly**, you can make it a method and call it with a reference to an object followed by *a dot* followed by a reference to the function:

```
var obj = {};
obj.printMethod = print;
obj.printMethod(); // Object
```

Note, that if you call the method without the dot, the context will fall back to the default one:

```
var printMethod = obj.printMethod;
printMethod(); // Window
```

**Lastly**, there is a way to assign a context is by using either [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/`apply` or `bind`:

```
print.call(obj, 1, 2); // Object
print.apply(obj, [ 1, 2 ]); // Object

var boundPrint = print.bind(obj);
boundPrint(); // Object
```

To better understand context, you might want to experiment with such simple examples. John Resig has [very nice interactive slides](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#22) on context in JavaScript, where you can learn and test yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Storing it in a variable lets you access it in other scopes where `this` may refer to something else.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html and [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) for more information about the `this`  keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` reference doesn't work when a method of a class is called from a DOM event. When a method of an object is used as an event handler for onclick, for example, the `this` pointer points to the DOM node where the event happened. So you have to create a private backup of `this` in the object.

Answer (score 1):

**this** is a keyword in javascript, not a default variable defined within every function, hence, as Gareth said, **this** will refer to the context in which the function is invoked, or the global object if there's no context.