# referring to prototype method within class variable

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm having trouble with a JS prototype object I'm working on. What I'm trying to do is define a class-level variable as an object literal, then refer back to one of the class's prototype methods to set a property of the class-level variable, but I'm not getting anywhere. Here's what I am trying to do, in a simplified example:

```
var foo = function(args)
{
    this.name = 'bar';
}
foo.stuff = { barbaz: this.foobarbaz(2) };

foo.prototype.foobarbaz(int)
{
    return int;
}

alert(foo.stuff.barbaz); // should alert 2, but I'm missing something
```

I'm wondering if I'm just misunderstanding the scope of 'this' in this instance, or if this.foobarbaz() is undefined when I assign it to foo.stuff.barbaz.

Is it possible to refer to an object's prototype methods from within a class-level variable like this?

Comment: First, you should define your method on the prototype like `foo.prototype.foobarbaz = function(int) {...}`. Second, you're trying to use the method *before* you define it. Third, in this function you've provided, `this` is not `foo`.

Comment: the omission of the function call on foo.prototype.foobarbaz was an error in writing the post - that is how I have it defined in my actual javascript file.

so in the scope of `foo.stuff`, is `this` referring to `foo.stuff`?

Comment: As I explain in my answer, `this` is always the same throughout the entirety of a single function; `this` does not change when you use it inside of an object literal. (However, it *may* change when used inside of a function definition, e.g., for a callback. As I also explain in my answer, a function's context (i.e. `this`) is set at function execution time and may vary depending on [how the function is invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370851/understanding-javascript-scope-with-var-that-this/12371105#12371105).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to know:

1. You should define your method on the prototype like `foo.prototype.foobarbaz = function(int) {...}`. Your current syntax is not valid.
2. You're trying to use the method before you define it. If you're expecting [function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting) to work here, that only applies to function declarations, not assignments. Move the assignment of `foobarbaz` above the first time you use it.
3. In this function you've provided, `this` is not `foo`. Each **function** has its own value of `this` (called the function's "*context*"), set each time the function is invoked. You can see the rules for how a function's context is set in several answers to [Understanding Javascript scope with "var that = this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370851/understanding-javascript-scope-with-var-that-this/12371105#12371105).

Instead, here, you'll need to use `foo.foobarbaz(2)` instead of `this.foobarbaz(2)`, because `this` is probably `window` (assuming you call this code not as the method of an object and not in JavaScript's `strict` mode).

Comment: thanks apsillers, this is good to get me going in the right direction.

Comment: yeah, figured it out. basically the takehome for me on this one is use the namespace of the function if you want to be sure to access it.