# Nested functions & the "this" keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this

"The `this` keyword always refers to the object that the containing function is a method of."

Great, sounds simple enough, but here's what I'm wondering about...

For example:

```
function func1() {

  function func2() {
    alert(this == window); // true
  }

  func2();

  alert(this == window); // true
}

func1.func3 = function () {

  alert(this == window); // false
  alert(this == func1); // true

};

func1();
func1.func3();
```

Now, since `func1` is actually a method of the *global* (`window`) object (a function object assigned to the property `func1` of the *global* object) it makes sense that `this` inside `func1` refers to the *global* object, and since `func3` is a method of `func1`'s function object it makes sense that `this` inside `func3` refers to `func1`'s function object.

The thing that bothers me is `func2`. I know that `this` inside a nested function is also supposed to reference the *global* object, but I'm not sure why since `func2` is NOT a method of the *global* object. As far as I understand (and this is the part I might be completely wrong about) `func2` is a method of `func1`'s call (activation / variable) object. Now, if I'm right about this (and I'm not sure that I am) then shouldn't `this` inside `func2` refer to `func1`'s call object instead of the *global* object?

So, I guess my question would be: Is a nested function a method of the call (activation) object of the function it is nested in, and if so, shouldn't `this` refer to that call object instead the *global* object?

Comment: Your "definition" of `this` is incomplete. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: A function's *context* (`this`) is determined *at execution time* and its value [depends on how the function invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370851/understanding-javascript-scope-with-var-that-this/12371105#12371105) for that particular execution. The value of `this` in a particular function may change from invocation to invocation, if it is called in a different way (e.g. as an object's method, from `call` or `apply`, etc).

Comment: @RobW Well, I did find several articles on the internet which use this definition of the keyword, but I suppose that they could be wrong, I'm still wondering about the nested functions part though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The this keyword always refers to the object that the containing function is a method of.

No. Unfortunately, it is not easy as that. The [documentation of the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) at MDN gives a good overview. It is set to the object when the function is called as a method *on* it, but there are other possibilies. The default is that `this` is `undefined` when it is called without anything special, like you do with `func1` and `func2`. For sloppy (non-strict) mode functions `undefined` (and `null`) are not used though, `this` does point to the global object (`window` in browsers) for them in that case - what you are observing.

But it could also point to fresh object instances when the function is called as a constructor (with the `new` keyword), or to an event target (like a DOM element) when used as a handler. Last, but not least, it could be set manually with `call`, `apply` or `bind`…

`this` has nothing to do with nesting. Nesting function declarations/expressions only affects the scope ("privacy", availability) of variables. While the variable scope of a function never changes, the value of `this` can be different on every invocation - it is more like an extra argument.

Comment: Well, I did find several articles on the internet which use this definition of the keyword, but I suppose that they could be wrong, I'm still wondering about the nested functions part though

Comment: Yet another case is that it could also be bound as an event listener, which runs with the context set to the target element.

Comment: Yes, I understand all that, but what I would like to know is if a nested function is a method of the call (activation) object of the function it is nested in?

Comment: No, it is just a function, stored somewhere. The call object of the invoking function does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of the `this` keyword inside a function depends on the way the function is invoked. There are 4 different function invocation patterns in JavaScript.

1. function invocation pattern `foo()`
2. method invocation pattern `o.foo()`
3. constructor invocation pattern `new foo`
4. call/apply pattern `foo.apply(...)` or `foo.call(...)`

Only in #2 is it the case that `this` inside the function refers to the object of which the function is a method.

You are invoking `func2()` with the function invocation pattern. When doing so, `this` refers to the global object.

As suggested by @Bergi, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for more detail on the meaning of `this` and the different function invocation patterns.

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm not sure why since func2 is NOT a method of the global object.

Any thing defined inside a function is local to the scope of that function. So `func2` belongs to the local scope of `func1` and therefore is not attached to `window`.

In Javascript, the value of `this` is generally based on how you call the function. When you call a function without any leading object, `this` is usually set to the global parent object, which is `window`.

You can explicitly set the value of `this` in three ways:

```
myObj.func(a, b); //this set to myObj implicitly because myObj is the parent 

func.call(myObj, a, b); //this set to myObj explicitly; the first argument 
                        //to call sets the value of this for that function

func.apply(myObj, [a, b]); //this set to myObj explicitly; the first argument
                           //to apply also sets the value of this for that
                           //function.
```

`this` can be a tricky concept. MDN has a [good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) about `this`.

Comment: While the statement is true, it doesn't hold as an answer to the question. You have to highlight the meaning and role of `this`, before the OP can truly understand what's going wrong.