# this points to null in a callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, this

As per [Nested functions & the "this" keyword in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410779/nested-functions-the-this-keyword-in-javascript) & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

I understood that when a function is called directly(i.e.not with an object) , this should point to the global object.

In the below **Node** code , after the comment "//why is this null??" i thought "this" should be pointing to the global object. But it instead is "null"...why?

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

function FileThing() {
  this.name = '';

  this.exists = function exists(cb) {
    console.log('Opening: ' + this.name);
    fs.open(this.name, 'r', function onOpened(err, fd) {
      if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') { // then file didn't exist
          //why is this null??
          console.log(this);
          console.log('Failed opening file: ' + this.name);
          return cb(null, false);
        }
        // then there was some other error
        return cb(err);
      }
      fs.close(fd);
      return cb(null, true);
    });
  };
}

var f = new FileThing();
f.name = 'thisFileDoesNotExist';
f.exists(function onExists(err, exists) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('ERROR! ' + err);
  }
  console.log('file ' + (exists ? 'DOES' : 'does NOT') + ' exist');
});
```

Comment: The Node code that invokes the callbacks can arrange for the value of `this` to be anything it wants.

Comment: so node explicitly sets this to null for some reason...so that we cant peek into the internals of global object?

Comment: I'm not sure - I can't find anything that documents that behavior. Note that in "strict" mode, lack of an explicit context for a function will result in `this` being `undefined`, not the global object.

Comment: Sorry, the answer you linked to was not entirely accurate, I did not differentiate between strict and sloppy mode there (fixed now). In your case I'd expect the `this` value to be `undefined`.