# Callbacks, anonymous functions and context

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between this code:

```
$('.percentage_field').change(function() {
    update_percentage();
});
$('.inspect1').change(function(){
    show_hide_targets();
});
```

And this code:

```
$('.percentage_field').change(
    update_percentage
);

$('.inspect1').change(
    show_hide_targets
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a callback runs in response to an event, `this` inside the function is set to the DOM element that is the target of the event.

In your first example, the anonymous function gets the `this` of the target element, but that `this` is *not forwarded to the inner function call*. Instead, the inner function runs with a `this` [according to how it is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370851/understanding-javascript-scope-with-var-that-this/12371105#12371105). (Here, it's a direct "raw" call (i.e., not called as a member function), so it runs with a `this` equal to `window`, in non-script mode.)

In your second example, the functions `update_percentage` and `show_hide_targets` get the `this` of the target element directly.

Consider [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/5F5nk/3):

```
function sayThis() { alert(this); }
someElem.addEventListener("click", function() { sayThis() });
someElem.addEventListener("click", sayThis);
someElem.addEventListener("click", function() { sayThis.call(this) });
```

The first will alert `window` (or `undefined` in strict mode); the second will alert the element the listener fired on. The third listener uses an anonymous function, but it invokes the inner function using [`.call(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), which forwards the original `this` to the inner function.