# Need for JavaScript call method on function object

Tags: javascript

Take a simple anonymous function which accepts 3 parameters:

```
function hello(firstname, surname, city) {
    console.log('Hi ' + firstname + ' ' +
                        surname + '. I see you\'re from ' + city)
}
```

**What is the benefit of calling this function using the function method "call" over say just calling the function?**, ie.

```
hello('Jane','Mansfield','Philadelphia');
```

vs

```
hello.call(this,'Jane','Mansfield','Philadelphia');
```

Fiddle-dee-dee: http://jsfiddle.net/wC3xz/1/

Sorry, but looking at the docs hasn't shed any light. The only thing I can think of is if you can gain access to the this object passed to the function. But wouldn't accessing this from within the anonymous function be this in the context of the anonymous function ie the window?

**When is call needed instead of just functionname(args)?**

Comment: `call` is only necessary if your function uses `this`. In the particular case of your `hello` function, you'll never see any difference because it doesn't use `this`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call Did you see this?

Comment: @aspillers but how do you access this within the destination function? surely it will be this in the context of the destination function not where you're calling from.

Comment: @dewd The value of `this` within a function changes [depending on how the function is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370851/understanding-javascript-scope-with-var-that-this/12371105#12371105). `call` allows you **circumvent the normal rules** and freely specify a `this` value.

Comment: @aspillers. Your link is the answer. Thx man.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### So what's the big deal about call?

Call is [defined in the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4) in section 15.3.4.4. You use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) when you are trying to set the thisArg inside the function.

### How would Ito use it?

Here is an example of *how* you would use it:

```
var me = { name: 'dr.eval' }

foo.call(me); // if you omitted the 'call' it would error because this defaults to the window object.

function foo() {
    alert(this.name + ' is home');
}
```

you can read more about it here: [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

### When would I use it?

Here is a very canonical example when using call:

A lot of DOM methods return `NodeList`. While NodeList is an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Working_with_Array-like_objects), you cannot natively call array methods on them. However, since they are, by design, *like* arrays, you can use array methods on them using `.call`

If you open the console and type

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").forEach
```

You'd get undefined, because it returns a NodeList, which does not have a forEach method. However, iterating a NodeList might be desirable, so you can do the following:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"),function(elem){
     console.log(elem);
});
```

Which would log all the anchor elements on the page.

Another common example is `arguments` which is another "Array Like" object. Often, we want to process arguments like an array but we can't. So again, `.call` comes to the rescue and we can do:

```
[].slice.call(arguments,0); // returns a clone of arguments, but a real array we can work with!
```

It's also useful when working with events, and in general it shows how flexible JavaScript is. It's a way to share functionality between objects that otherwise would not have been able to share it.

Comment: Nice, I added a more common example.

Comment: @dr.eval Thanks so much. This clarifies it nicely.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thx for playing policeman on this one. You really helped reiterate the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @dewd You're welcome. That's the only way we can keep SO a high quality Q&A site. If people do not answer your question don't be afraid to tell them that. Your question was solid and if dr.eval hadn't answered it I would have done so myself. I'm satisfied with this answer atm.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yep me too. I can take the examples and clearly see the difference.

Comment: I want you all to know that I die a little inside every time you instantiate an array just to hijack its methods.

Comment: @canon I don't care :) You're welcome to change it to Array.prototype if you'd like.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've just discovered that your example can be done without call. Try: Array.slice(arguments). Not sure how supported it is, but it's in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: @dr.eval Same goes with foreach. Array.forEach(document.getElementsByTagName("a"),function(elem){
     console.log(elem);}) works. No call required.

Comment: @dr.eval in the foo example, what's wrong with console.log(arguments[0].name)? No need for call there.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the benefit of calling this function using the function method "call" over say just calling the function?**

- None. It is useful only if you want to transfer context (**this**) to the function

**When is call needed instead of just functionname(args)?**

- when you want to call existing method in different context than it is defined. For example, **arguments** object is similar to `Array`, but you can not use `sort()` directly.

  ```
  function Test() {
    // call sort from Array context onto arguments object
    console.log(Array.prototype.sort.call(arguments)); // 2 3 5 8
    // error: arguments object doesn't contain sort
    console.log(arguments.sort());
  }
  Test(5,3,8,2);
  ```

Comment: @dewd This is an another good example of when to use `call` , again, we have an array like object (arguments) and we're calling `.sort` on it, which we would otherwise not have been able to.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeah, I saw it and have given it a +1

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
.call
```

and

```
.apply
```

when it comes to overriding.

[`this`](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx) is a good article to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of using call() in general is that it allows you to set the context for the function explicitly. There's not much value in that for a simple function as you show, but if your function is a method of an object or if it's a callback, setting the context can be relevant.

Comment: _HOW_ can it be relevant? Methods and callbacks are two _good_ examples, can you explain _why_ setting this might be useful in such a scenerio?