# How does 'this' works in javascript?

Tags: javascript

hi i am a little confusion on how exactly `this` works in javascript.Based on this example:

```
var myFunction = function(){
 function testMe(){
  console.log(this)  --------> DOMwindow
 }
 console.log(this) ---------> myFunction
}

var myvariable = new myFunction();
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/80127/710446 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12370851/710446

Comment: Your `testMe` is never called?

Comment: Searching is your friend.

Comment: ah, thanks i got answer from In Javascript, why is the "this" operator inconsistent?

Comment: @DeepakNair I'm glad you found your answer.  Please do search on Google and other Stack Overflow answers first before posting a question.  It helps us focus the site with high-quality questions and answers, and also if you post too many low-quality questions, you'll get an automatic question ban.

Answer (score 5):

The value `this` references depends on circumstances. Any unscoped (i.e. not in an object) function call will have `this` = `window` (`DOMWindow`, if you prefer). Anything that is part of a prototype, or has been changed using `apply` or `bind`, will have `this` as that object ("itself", if you prefer).

So, to illustrate. When you are instantiating using the `new` keyword, your function automatically inherits `this` as itself. When you call an IETF within it, `this` within this IETF will point to the global scope.

If you would like to avoid this, instead of calling `testMe` literally, you can always do this:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var testMe = function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    testMe.bind(this);
}
```

Which will, in turn, have `this` within `testMe` use the object as it should.

Comment: "The value this references changes on every function call based on what actually happens". Not at all. The value of *this* is set by the call and can be the same value every time. It can also be set to a fixed value using *bind* in ES5 compliant browsers.

Comment: @RobG: Fine, I'll edit to "the value this references is dependent on circumstances" to be more vague.

Comment: " When you are instantiating using the new keyword, your function automatically inherits this as itself". Not correct either. When a function is called as a constructor, its *this* references a newly constructed object. You've also ignored strict mode in ES5, where *this* can be **any** value, including undefined.