# Javascript this keyword and variables pointing to an object method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how the `this` keyword works in this context.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sayName = function() {
        alert('My name is ' + this.name);
    };
}


var p = new Person('Smith');
p.sayName();  // 'My name is Smith'

var q = p;

q.sayName();  // 'My name is Smith'

q = p.sayName;

q();  // 'My name is'   ???
```

Why is the last example not picking up 'Smith'?

Is it because q is simply pointing to a function (i.e. the object the method belongs to is not recognized in this context)? Since q is in the global space, `this` is global within the function (i.e. the caller of sayName() is the global space or window)?

Comment: Because it all depends on how the function is called. In your last example, it has no context, so `this` is actually `window`. To overcome this problem, put `var that = this;` inside your `Person` function. Then, use `that` throughout to refer to the specific `Person` instances

Comment: `this` inside the a function is determined at invocation time depending on [how the function was invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12371105/710446). `p.sayName()` and `q()` are different styles of invocation; the first is as a method of an object, the second as a "raw" function call.

Comment: I thought q = p.sayName created context, because sayName() is part of p.  So, assigning a variable to a method, even if it looks like it is part of an object, is just creating a raw function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `this` refers to the context that the function is called from. When you do `p.sayName()` the context is `p`. If you just call a function without context, it will default to the global context (usually `window`) or `undefined` in strict mode.

If you want to make it work the way you were expecting you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `this` to `p`, so that `q()`:

```
q = p.sayName.bind(p);

q(); // My name is Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on what @Paulpro said, you can create a reference to the `Person()` context by adding `var that = this;` inside the class.  That way you could call `that.name` from inside the function.

```
function Person(name) 
{
    var that = this;

    this.name = name;
    this.sayName = function() 
    {
        alert('My name is ' + that.name);
    };
}


var p = new Person('Smith');
p.sayName();  // 'My name is Smith'

var q = p;

q.sayName();  // 'My name is Smith'

q = p.sayName;

q();  // 'My name is Smith'
```

***[View jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HsNXr/)***