# jQuery ajaxform submit callback issue

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I am using ajaxform to handle my form submissions and have encountered a problem with the option variable. I am trying to have the success callback append some HTML to a relative element, as such I am using the `$(this)` approach as I would do normally. I can't get it to work, am I missing something simple here? Is there any reason why `$(this)` will not work? The plugin url is http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Thanks in advance

A

The selector references the  element so on submit the ajaxform plugin fires. It is as follows `$('#formSEIncome').ajaxForm(options)`

The options jQuery is as follows:

```
var options = {             
       success: function() { 
       $(this).parents('.trm_expense_cats').find('.itemlist').append('<li>Test</li>');
        alert('ok');
    }   // post-submit callback 
};
```

Comment: what  `$(this)` refer? Show ur full ajax code?

Comment: Try logging `this`. I don't think it is what you expect. You may have to save `$(this)` to a variable outside the callback and use that variable inside the callback.

Comment: Likely duplicate of [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6394812/710446), but there's not enough info here to say for sure.

Comment: Sorry please see above edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to use the provided success functionality in the jQuery plugin rather than what I did above. So

Event handler:

```
$('#formSEIncome').ajaxForm(options)
```

Options variable:

```
var options = { 
        target:        this  // target element to be updated with server response 
        ,success:       showResponse          
};
```

Success function:

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
$form.parents('.trm_expense_cats').find('.itemlist').append('<li>Test</li>');
    alert('ok');
}
```

As such the use of `this` in the options.success object solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is set by each function when it is invoked. Your code looks like this:

```
// OUTSIDE the callback

var options = {             
       success: function() { 
         // INSIDE the callback
         $(this).parents('.trm_expense_cats').find('.itemlist').append('<li>Test</li>');
         alert('ok');
    }
};

// OUTSIDE the callback
$('#formSEIncome').ajaxForm(options)
```

You probably expect that `this` is the same value both inside and outside the callback, [but it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80084/in-javascript-why-is-the-this-operator-inconsistent). The callback sets its own value of `this` [depending on how it is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371105/710446). Here, the callback decides the value of `this` inside the callback when it runs.

If you want to save your "outer" `this`, see [$(this) inside of AJAX success not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6394812/710446) for how to use `$.proxy`. You can also save your outer `this` in a variable (often named `that`) outside your callback. Since JavaScript functions have access to the variables of their containing functions, the callback will have access to `that`:

```
// OUTSIDE the callback
// save outer this
var that = this;

var options = {             
       success: function() { 
         // INSIDE the callback
         // we use that, not this, to get the outer this
         $(that).parents('.trm_expense_cats').find('.itemlist').append('<li>Test</li>');
         alert('ok');
    }
};

// OUTSIDE the callback
$('#formSEIncome').ajaxForm(options)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So to clarify, could I do the following: `var options = {     $this: $(this),        
       success: function() { 
       options.$this.parents('.trm_expense_cats').find('.itemlist').append('<li>Test</li>');
        alert('ok');
    }   // post-submit callback 
};`

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help out. I have tried that and console log tells me ... Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined. I can't see how this is true given the above code?

Comment: `$this` *is* undefined. The `$this` property of `options` is defined. In your `success` function, are you trying to use `options.$this` (good, `options` is defined and has a property called `$this`) or just `$this` (not good, not defined)?

Comment: Sorry yes, it is defined now (I had `$this` in console log rather than `options.$this`) I have fixed this but it won't append to the suggested element eg... `var options = {         
  $this: $(this)
                ,success: function() { 
      options.$this.append('<div>Test</div>');
      console.log(options.$this);
  } 
};` I would have hoped this would append the DIV to `#formSEIncome`. I think I'm missing something silly here

Comment: Thanks for all your help apsillers, I have managed to sort this now. Cheers A