# About this keyword bests uses in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I have a couple of questions about the "this" keyword use on javascript.

---

1. It is true that the constant use of `this` overloads the entire function object into the RAM memory?
2. It's better to declare

---

```
MyClass = function(){ 
    this.name = "Petter";
    this.age = 12;
    this.toString = function(){
        return "Name: "+this.name + " Age: " + this.age;  
    }
}
```

instead of

---

```
MyClass = function(){
    var _this = this;
    _this.name = "Petter";
    _this.age = 12;
    _this.toString = function(){
        return "Name: "+_this.name + " Age: " + _this.age;  
    }
}
```

or what can you recommend to me?

Comment: [Javascript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not true, I've never even heard of such a thing.

All you are doing when you do

```
var _this = this;
```

Is creating a variable to point to the object in memory that is referred to when you use `this`. Whether you say:

```
this.name = "Petter";
```

or

```
_this.name = "Petter";
```

You are still assigning a property to the same object. The way you reference that object (`_this` or `this`) makes no difference.

**EDIT**

You often need to get a reference to `this` when you want to use `this` in a different scope (setTimeout's come to mind as a good example).

```
    var MyClass = function() {
       setTimeout(function() { this.myMethod(); },100);
    };

    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
      console.log('hi there');
    }

    var myObject = new MyClass();
```

In the above code, you would get an error because when the setTimeout function gets executed, it does so in the global scope where `this === window` and you have no function called `myMethod()` on the `window` object.

To correct that, you would do this:

```
    var MyClass = function() {
       var self = this;
       setTimeout(function() { self.myMethod(); },100);
    };

    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
      console.log('hi there');
    }

    var myObject = new MyClass();
```

Even though your setTimeout function is executed in the global scope, the variable `self` actual points to an instance of `MyClass` (or `this`) because you did `self = this` (and because JavaScript is [lexically scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope/7527861#7527861).

Also, and this is just personal preference, you'll quite often see this:

```
var self = this;
```

instead of

```
var _this = this;
```

Not a big deal, but it's just a convention I thought might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Or `var me = this` :)

Comment: Do people do `var self = this;` and `var me = this` because they're accustomed to other languages that actually use `me` or `self` as the keyword rather than `this`?  Or is there some other reason?

Comment: @nhgrif Suppose `functionA` is run with some `this`. That function defines some `functionB` that needs to use the `this` from `functionA`. But if `functionB` uses the `this` keyword, it will refer to `functionB`'s *own* `this`. We get around this problem by assigning `functionA`'s `this` to another identifier, asscessible from `functionB`. See [Understanding Javascript scope with “var that = this”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370851/understanding-javascript-scope-with-var-that-this/12371105#12371105)

Comment: @nhgrif it's basically down to the fact you can't scope `this`, if you want to, you have to keep the reference as a different variable. i.e. function `A` uses `this`, inside function `A` there is another function defined, `B`. The `this` in `A` is not necessarily the same as the `this` in `B`. Solution: assign `this` to a variable in `A`. **edit** you beat me to it

Comment: I was mainly asking about the naming convention, but thanks.  ;)

Comment: If you prefer consistency of the `this` keyword, some Javascript toolkits provide a special method for creating inline functions that are guaranteed a particular object to be 'this'. It's useful when writing small "setTimeout" functions. I know for dojo, it's `dojo.hitch(this, function())`, or `dojo.hitch(this, "nameOfMyFunction")`. There may be a similar function in JQuery.

Comment: @Katana314 - you can do that very easy in vanilla JavaScript using `.bind()` (not supported in IE8),  `.call()`, or `.apply()`

Comment: @Adam You learn something new every day! Sounds useful if one could drop IE8 support; call and apply are meant for immediate calling though, rather than saving a function for later. When it's appropriate, I agree I prefer to use those, over mangling a dojo.hitch into an immediate call.

Answer (score 0):

For the first point it would be in the RAM anyway, I can't say why referencing it with this constantly would change anything.

As for the second point, it is better to store the objects this reference in a variable such as self or _this because in Javascript when you call a function the context of the function can be manipulated by the call and apply functions which will then change what this means.

so with this:

```
MyClass = function(){ 
    this.name = "Petter";
    this.age = 12;
    this.toString = function(){
        return "Name: "+this.name + " Age: " + this.age;  
    }
}
myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.call({name: 'bob', age: '15'});
```

The line myObject.call will actually change the reference to this in toString so it will return the "Name: Bob Age: 15" not "Name: Peter Age: 12"

Comment: Gabriel, you did hit the nail of my question, because that's an interesting reference. I know how to use this but I wasn't clear about that issue: manipulation of objects. Today I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you may be confusing the fact that if you don't use [the `new` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) when instantiating your objects, you duplicate prototype functions associated with each object instance.
2. As mentioned in Adam's answer, you are just using more memory by adding another variable. By convention, you will usually see [variable names prefixed with an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484424/underscore-prefix-for-property-and-method-names-in-javascript) when they are private instance variables.