# Why is `this` in a passed method/function different than in a method call on a passed object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started playing around with node.js (and javascript) and may have a fundamental misunderstanding. The following code works as expected. It is taken from a tutorial for a simple API with express, except for the extracted function to get the data (but the problem also occurs with restify except for a less informative stack trace).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var getdataandsend = function(request,response) {
        var res = {a:1,b:2}; // actually sql query using request.params
        response.send(res);
    }
app.get('/:id', function (request, response) {
    getdataandsend(request,response);});

var server = app.listen(1234, function () {});
```

However, since I only pass `response` to `getandsenddata` in order to call its `send` method, I figured that I might as well pass a reference/pointer to the method itself instead of the whole object:

```
var getdataandsend = function(request,respfun) {
        respfun({a:1,b:2}); 
    }
app.get('/:id', function (request, response) {
    getdataandsend(request,response.send);});
```

But this results in the following

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
   at send (...\test\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:103:17)
   at getdataandsend (...\test\misctest.js:6:9)
   at ...\test\misctest.js:9:6
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\test\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
...
```

The relevant line in [response.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js) is `var req = this.req;`, which is the first occurence of a variable of that name in that file. Apparently, the value of `this` is different between the two calls above, even though the response object's method `send` is called from the same place (`getdataandsend`). Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371105/6280519) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80478/6280519) the observed behavior might make sense if the first call is considered a method and the second a function call, but why would that be the case? `send` is still a method of `response`, isn't it? Or are both function calls (...then what is `response`)?

Comment: The more highly-voted answer there has a lot more information than the accepted answer, so be sure to read both.

Answer (score 1):

In *JavaScript*, every function has a `this` object associated with it. This is used to store the data/execution context of the function.

In case of a constructor function or a method, the `this` object stores the public context of the object to which this method belongs.

However, if a function is not a constructor or a method, then the `this` object stores the global context, which is `window` in case of the browser, and `GLOBAL` for NodeJS.

It is possible to *set* the `this` object of a function ***to any context*** by using the native `call`, `apply` or `bind` functions.

[Link for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

---

**What happens in your case** is that when you are sending the `response.send` function to the `getdataandsend` function, you are actually stripping the `send` function from the `this` context of the `response` object.

So, when the `send` function, internally, tries to access anything from the `this` context, it gets an `undefined`, and consequently an error.