# Why `this` refers to the parent function's scope

Tags: javascript

I did read that the `this` keyword can refer to either the global scope or to the object it is being referred in or to the object to which an event is bound but the below behavior is not understood.

```js
function outer() {
  var inner = 4;

  function innerFunc() {
    var inner = 5;
    console.log('inner called with ' + this.inner);
  }
  return innerFunc;
}
var obj = outer();
obj();
```

Why does this log 4 instead of 5. AFAIK `this` should refer to the function it is being referred in and should be available via `closure`.

Comment: it does neither, it logs `undefined`. `this` is the global object for this invocation, basically because there's no reason for it to be anything else.

Comment: Please leave the snippet running

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to *any* function btw, although this is a common and somewhat-understandable misconception. I recommend reading the first 2 chapters of this: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md

Comment: @RobinZigmond My Bad. I was randomly executing functions in developer tools where I might have defined x globally as 4. Refreshing the window started giving undefined.

Comment: Heads up!! `this` doesn't really make much sense unless you use `new`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript this of the outer function of closure having a bound 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574677/javascript-this-of-the-outer-function-of-closure-having-a-bound-this)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - `this` doesn't work like you think it should.

Read more [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md), [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

The `this` (otherwise known as context) of a function is determined at **call time**, not at function definition time. This is widely known as `this` being *dynamically bound*, and variables from closure being *lexically bound*.

```
var obj = outer();
obj();
```

Calls `outer` with `this = window` (or `global` in the case of Node.js) because you are not in strict mode (otherwise, `this = undefined`). `outer` doesn't use `this`, so this doesn't impact it greatly.

`outer` then returns a function (`innerFunc`), and you assign it to `obj`. You then call `obj`, again, with `this = window` (because you didn't specify anything other with [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply)).

You then log `this.inner` which is equivalent to `window.inner` which is `undefined` unless you happen to have a global variable named `inner` with some value.

---

The value of `this`, then, is determined by the caller.

If you had invoked `obj` like so:

```
obj.call({inner: 42}); // first argument to fn.call() is the context
```

You would have seen 42 in your console, regardless of how the function was defined.

A way to mitigate this and retain control over your `this` is to either use [`fn.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is returning `undefined`, not 4. The reason for this is because the `window` is calling `innerFunc` by invoking `obj()`. Thus, `this` is referring to the `window` as that is what called `innerFunc` (and `window.inner` is `undefined`). You can see this by adding a variable `inner = 3` at the top of your code (this will make `window.inner = 3`) and so your function will log `3`.

```js
inner = 3; // ie: window.inner = 3
function outer() {
  var inner = 4;

  function innerFunc() {
    var inner = 5;
    console.log('inner called with ' + this.inner); // this is window
  }
  return innerFunc;
}
var obj = outer();
obj();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example you are using a **function** instead of an **object**. Additionally, you used a variable instead of the `this` keyword to assign the value. I think the concept that you're thinking of is `local scoping`

For example,

```
function parent(){
var n = 5
    function child(){
         var n = 4 //n is 4 here
    }
//n is 5 here
}
```